# How to better visualize features of clusters in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers-2, clustering

I am using the cluster strategy for mapping a large number of features in OpenLayers, now I would like to find a good solution for providing info about the features contained in a cluster selected by the user. In other words whenever the user selects one cluster I would like to explode the cluster with as many markers as the features contained in it, of course selectable markers.

Could anybody help me?

I attached an image about how the markers around the selected cluster would look like.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is accessing to the clustered elements or to create the expanding animation?

This is what I use to access to any feature attribute:

```
                if(feature.attributes.count>1) {
                    var sumValue = 0;
                    for (var i=0; i<feature.cluster.length; i++) {
                        sumValue += feature.cluster[i].attributes['val'];
                    }
                    var averageValue = sumValue/feature.cluster.length;
                    return averageValue.toFixed(1);
                } else return feature.attributes.val;
```

In that way I get the clustered elements' values average, but this allows you to get every clustered elements value and show it.

You can set attributes in that way:

```
            var pointFeature = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(lon,lat));       
            pointFeature.attributes = {
                val: mks[i].m,
                id: mks[i].id,
            };
            features[i] = pointFeature;
```

Comment: Thanks alberto for your answer.Actually I know how to access the clusters' elements, my problem is related to how to explode

Comment: Sorry Alberto. Actually I know how to access the clusters' elements, my problem is related to how to explode the features around that selected cluster. In other words I would like to draw around the cluster as many markers as the features contained in the cluster.